# Convert hardcoding - use dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

> Here is where I am with my procedure using the BULK loading capability
>   of 11G.  How can I convert this to use dynamic SQL so I don't have to
>   hardcode the source and target tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Ld_Partition_Tbl 
(p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10000) IS

TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF *SourceTableName*%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM *SourceTableName*;

BEGIN

  OPEN c;
    LOOP
      FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT p_array_size;

      FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
      INSERT INTO *TargetTableName* VALUES l_data(i);

      EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE c;

END Ld_Partition_Tbl;
```

I need to replace the SourceTableName and TargetTableName with parameters, but need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Although you may convert the whole procedure into a dynamic anonymous block, it's not advisable to go down that path because dynamic sqls are harder to manage and debug. I would suggest you to write static blocks of code for all the tables involved with `FORALL` or more efficiently, just  plain old insert statements one per table( may be by increasing temp space sufficiently to avoid the need for Bulk DML/ Forall)

Answer (score 1):

From what you have provided you can simply run this. You don't need to store the data in an intermediate variable `l_data`.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' ||*TargetTableName*||' SELECT * FROM ' ||*SourceTableName*;
```